# C# wpf - MenuItem Header that loads from xml file (with accelerator [alt clicking] shortcut)

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem

I am trying to create a Multi-Language WPF program that will load it's languages from an xml path, though i'm having problem loading a MenuItem translation and give it it's accelerator.

Here's the main code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Lang" Source="/lang/english.xml" XPath="Language/MainWindow"/>
</Window.Resources>
<MenuItem Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource Lang}, XPath=MenuItems/MenuItemFile/@Header}"/>
```

Here's how my language file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Language>
    <MainWindow>
    <MenuItems>
        <MenuItemFile Header="File" />
    </MenuItems>
    </MainWindow>
</Language>
```

**My problem is:**
in this state of the language file it's all ok, but when i am trying to change the Header of MenuItemFile to "_File" (to give it an accelerator option), the program starts and gives the File menu the Header "_File" and not "File" (and an accelerator).

Thanks in advanced,
Din.

Comment: You know about WPF's built in localization constructs right? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to `AccessText` instead of binding to `Header` directly:

```
<MenuItem>
    <MenuItem.Header>
        <AccessText Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Lang}, XPath=MenuItems/MenuItemFile/@Header}"/>
    </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```